# Cannot check in a page after updating it

Tags: error, check-in

Has anyone encountered the Microsoft correlation ID-related error coming up when try to check in a page aftery you updated it? When I checked the logs, this is the specific error message I see:

"Invalid SPListItem. The SPListItem provided is not compatible with a Publishing Page"

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks,

Karen

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help you out

http://blog.dennus.net/2011/07/28/sharepoint-2007-to-2010-site-upgrade-problems-and-solutions/

Let us know.